# Overwrite CSS applied in jQuery with normal CSS (without !important)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*So I got the following problem:*

I got an element with this CSS (`$(this)` is the cloned object):

```
clone.css({
   'width': $(this).width() + 'px',
   'height': $(this).height() + 'px',
   'top': $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + 'px',
   'left': $(this).offset().left + 'px',
   'position': 'fixed'
});
```

On click I add following class:

```
.dupe{
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:300px;
   border-radius:0;
   box-shadow:none;
   transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

That doesn't work tho, because jQuery overwrites it. I don't want to use `!important`.

So is there a way to tell the CSS like "now you're important and now you're not", without using `!important`?

Comment: Remove inline `css` and then apply `class`

Comment: Take a look at [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Inline `style` attributes will always take precedence.

Comment: @Archer: Tricky when the styling is derived at runtime as above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah - that was a total brain fart.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `jQuery.css` sets the style as inline styles on the element. You will need to use `!important` to override it from a stylesheet.

One way of handling this would be to use class names for all styles and use classes to toggle the styles.

If that is not an option, you can use `jQuery.css` after click to either reset the properties to their initial values (by setting them to `''`) or set them to the values they need to be.

Live example of setting them to `''`:

```js
var clone = $(".target").clone();
clone.css({
   'width': '80px',
   'height': '20px',
   'top': '40px',
   'left': '50%',
   'position': 'fixed'
});
clone.appendTo(document.body);
console.log("Added styling to clone");
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Removed styling from clone");
  clone.addClass("dupe").css({
     'width': '',
     'height': '',
     'top': '',
     'left': '',
     'position': ''
  });
}, 800);
```

```css
.target {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.dupe {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  Hi there
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You could also remove the style attribute entirely using `jQuery.removeAttr` if that is an option too. This will effectively remove inline styling allowing your other styles to kick in. But it will also remove any *other* inline styles that the elements have.

Live Example of removing the `style` attribute entirely:

```js
var clone = $(".target").clone();
clone.css({
   'width': '80px',
   'height': '20px',
   'top': '40px',
   'left': '50%',
   'position': 'fixed'
});
clone.appendTo(document.body);
console.log("Added styling to clone");
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Removed styling from clone");
  clone.addClass("dupe").removeAttr("style");
}, 800);
```

```css
.target {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.dupe {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  Hi there
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery adds it's styles as inline which always overwrite regular css without the !important tag. The best I can think of is making a function to apply the dupe class as inline styles also.

Something like:

```
object.css({
    'top':'0',
    'left':'0',
    'width':'100%',
    'height':'300px',
    'border-radius':'0',
    'box-shadow':'none',
    'transition':'all .3s ease-in-out'
});
```